# Can I just cut date palm branches

Tags: palm, branches

I'm growing a date palm (look at my [other post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22544/date-palm-just-growing-in-height-but-not-getting-a-trunk)) since some years.

This works more or less well but it has a lot of braches which won't hold up anymore and start to turn brown (but are still mostly green).

My question: Do you know if it harms the plant if I just cut the old branches? It has quite a lot of new ones in the centre.

Thanks a lot!

Ron

Comment: I checked the other post - can you please add a photograph of what it looks like now because the earlier post is 2 years ago. And its not a date palm, by the looks of it...

Comment: I agree, not a date palm, maybe a Kentish palm grown under low light

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but indepedent of the type of palm... Is pruning the branches ok?

Comment: And finally: I'm pretty sure it's a date palm. Someone I know grew it from a date seed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem. Trim off any branches that are brown or don't look good. Leave enough to let the plant feed itself.

I'm forever trimming up my houseplants.